# Getting the page title from a database query in Notion API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, notion-api

Both the index and key for each property_name from a database query are dynamic. The only constant is the type: "title" for the title property. The title itself is also nested in an array. I've marked it as I NEED THIS in the schema below. Furthermore, only one property is type: "title".

I have tried just about every object and array prototype function in various combinations , but due to the nested objects and arrays, and the property_name index and key being unknown, I cant figure it out.

My desired result would be to obj.map() the plain_text title and page_id of each page in the result to a JSX object.

Schema:

```
{
    object
    results [
        {
            object: page
            page_id: 442k3j423j4hk23kjh423
            created_time
            last_edited
            parent {
                type
                database_id 
            }
            archived 
            url
            properties {
                property_name {
                    id
                    type: 'title'
                    title [
                        plain_text: 'I NEED THIS'
                        id
                    ]
                }
                property_name {
                    id
                    type
                }
                property_name {
                    id
                    type
                }
            }
        },
        {
            object: page
            id
            created_time
            last_edited
            parent {
                type
                database_id 
            }
            archived 
            url
            properties {
                property_name {
                    id
                    type
                }
                property_name {
                    id
                    type
                }
                property_name {
                    id
                    type
                }
            }
        },
    ]

}
```

Desired resulting object for mapping:

```
var pages {
    page1: {
        page_id: '23j4lk23j4lk23j',
        page_title: 'This is a title'
    }
    page1: {
        page_id: '23j4lk23j4lk23j',
        page_title: 'This is a title'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Understand the Below Inner Map Concept and implement in your Code**

First of all,To Access the Main Datas lets Assume,

**const handleData = res.data**

Here you need the page_id and plain_text, To fetch those data...
*Do some inner map methods like this*

```
handleData.map((item)=> (
     item.results.map((inneritem)=> ( <p> {inneritem.page_id} </p> 
    inneritem.title.map((nesteditem)=> ( <p> {nesteditem.plain_text} </p> ) )
    ))
))
```

Comment: This would work great if each page only had one property, but each page has multiple properties, but only one property is the title and contains the title[] array.

Answer (score 0):

I use [notion_client](https://pypi.org/project/notion-client/) for interaction with the site.
This snippet getting a page and print title

```
client = notion_client.Client(auth=notion_token)
response = client.databases.retrieve(notion_database_id)
print(response['title'][0]['plain_text'])
```

---

The notion has bad API and documentation

Comment: I know how to get info from a single page, as the title is a top level key when you request a single page, the problem arises only in querying a database (to list every page in a database), as every page in the resulting list has the title listed underneath a property object, which is dynamic, so cant be retrieved with normal indexing or .key notation.

I could do a .map() and submit an API request for each page I get from the DB Query, but that is potentially hundreds of API requests for a single DB Query, which is  ridiculous when I already have the data, just don't know how to get to it.

Comment: @Eli were you able to find the solution for this? Had high hopes with Notion API, but turns out to be really difficult when it comes to implementing 

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```js
async function getPostsTitle(){
      const response = await notion.databases.query({
        database_id: 'your database id'
      }) 
      return response.results.map(post => post.properties.Name.title.map(item => item.plain_text)); 
    }
```